# Android Youtube sdk resolution issue

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have an android app with Youtube SDK integrated using [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858).

For some of the videos the quality of the video does not go above 240p. Is that a sdk issue? I'm having a feeling the sdk has been optimized for mobile devices or the original videos do not have that resolution.
Is there a way in which the resolution can go up to 360p?